# Setting text to a text view from a string.xml not working

Tags: android

So I the code that follows to set text view text to a string however when I run the app nothing shows in the text view, can anyone explain why?

**code:**

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
    Object poem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    if(poem.toString() == "Tam O Shanter"){
         selectedPoem.setText(getString(R.string.tamO));
    }
}
```

Comment: `poem.toString() == "Tam O Shanter"` needs to be `"Tam O Shanter".equals(poem.toString())` (better yet use `equalsIgnoreCase()`) See if that helps, it's one problem anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (poem.toString() == "Tam O Shanter"){
   selectedPoem.setText(getString(R.string.tamO));
}
```

This will always return false because you are comparing **references** not values. You have to use `equals()` method.

There is one golden rule: *Every time you want to compare Strings, equals() will become your friend.*

You need to do it like this:

```
if (poem.toString().equals("Tam O Shanter")) { // or equalsIgnoreCase()
   selectedPoem.setText(getString(R.string.tamO));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also rewrite also you code

```
String poem = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

You are suppose to equals instead of  == to compare 2 string

```
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
    String poem = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    if(poem.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Tam O Shanter")){
         selectedPoem.setText(getString(R.string.tamO));
    }
  }
```